# Extend backround-image via LESS - add rule to existing one

Tags: css, less

I have problem with this code -

```
<div class="banner-wrapper" style="background-image:linear-gradient(0deg, #00000088 50%, #ffffff44 120%), url('/banners/banner.png');">
    <p>Some banner text</p>
</div>
```

It is generated by PHP, I can't make the rule in LESS, becouse i don't know URL of that picture, it's dynamic.

But i need the oportunity to change the linear-gradient property. Can I say image url like this `<div class="banner-wrapper" style="url('/banners/banner.png');"></div>` and extend it via LESS than?

Comment: you have inline style which has a higher weight than CSS. I really don't know what you intend to do with LESS here. It's not a Case for either LESS, SASS or CSS. In the end there is no rule to it but a simply insert of variables. No matter if it is CSS, SASS or LESS.

Comment: I hoped that exists something like (pure imagination):
.banner-wrapper {
    extend-existing(background-image: linear-gradient(...));
}
or some rule to expand it to do the same, but i can tardet banners and changing property for each individuly...

Comment: SASS and LESS are preprocessors. That means that they compile the scss file to a normal CSS file that will be served to the browser. In the end you'll have a standard CSS file that cannot read out inline properties and only can overwrite those with the usage of `!important`